# Agrupar eventos por dia con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando en un pequeño sistema de eventos y quiero agrupar los que hay en el dia actual y los que estan por venir, dejando a un lado los que ya pasaron.

Esta es mi tabla eventos

```
id | nota             | fecha
-------------------------------
1  | Reunion con AG   | 2021-10-20 15:30:00
2  | Cumple de Mica   | 2021-10-14 08:00:00
3  | Marketing con AG | 2021-10-01 09:00:00
```

enevetos.php

```
<?php

$hoy = date('Y-m-d');

$evento = $hache->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM eventos");

while($rowevento = $evento->fetch()){

    // solo tomo la fecha y no la hora
    $campodatetime = $rowevento['fecha'];
    $date = date_create($campodatetime);
    $fecha = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');

    if($fecha == $hoy){
        echo "Hoy<br>". $rowevento['nota'].'<br>';
    } else{
        echo 'En la semana<br>'. $rowevento['nota'].'<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

respuesta

```
En la semana
Reunion con AG
hoy
Cumple de Mica
En la semana
Marketing con AG
```

Lo que quiero lograr es listas los eventos de hoy y aparte los eventos que vendran.

Los eventos pasados como este: `3  | Marketing con AG | 2021-10-01 09:00:00`, no deberian estar en la lista.

Como puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias

Comment: Para obtener sólo los eventos a partir de la fecha actual puedes modificar tu consulta así: **`SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE fecha >= CURDATE()`**

Answer (score 0):

Como comentaron, podrías hacer el filtro de fecha desde base de datos, pero si no, éste puede ser un ejemplo de solución:

```
<?php

/** Tu Data
    id | nota             | fecha
    -------------------------------
    1  | Reunion con AG   | 2021-10-20 15:30:00
    2  | Cumple de Mica   | 2021-10-14 08:00:00
    3  | Marketing con AG | 2021-10-01 09:00:00
    4  | Cena con XD      | 2021-10-31 07:00:00
*/

$a['id'] = 1;
$a['nota'] = 'Reunion con AG';
$a['fecha'] = '2021-10-20 15:30:00';

$b['id'] = 2;
$b['nota'] = 'Cumple de Mica';
$b['fecha'] = '2021-10-14 08:00:00';

$c['id'] = 3;
$c['nota'] = 'Marketing con AG';
$c['fecha'] = '2021-10-01 09:00:00';

$d['id'] = 4;
$d['nota'] = 'Cena con XD';
$d['fecha'] = '2021-10-31 07:00:00';

$eventos = [$a, $b, $c, $d];
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');

$mensajeHoy = 'Hoy:<br/>';
$mensajeFuturo = 'En la semana:<br/>';

foreach ($eventos as $rowevento) {
    
    $campodatetime = $rowevento['fecha'];
    $fecha = new DateTime($campodatetime);
    $fecha = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');

    if($fecha == $hoy){
        $mensajeHoy .= '* ' . $rowevento['nota'] . '<br/>';
    } else if($fecha > $hoy){
        $mensajeFuturo .= '* ' . $rowevento['nota'] . '<br/>';
    } else {
        // Aqui podrias hacer alguna otra cosa con los eventos pasados
    }
}

echo($mensajeHoy . '<br/>' . $mensajeFuturo);

?>
```

Acerca de DateTime para comparar las fechas, puedes leer más [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)

Comment: me gusta esta respuesta con ejemplo y documentación de referencia...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar una consulta, agrupando por fecha y sacando los eventos con un [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select
    date_format(fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') as fecha,
    group_concat(nota)
from
    eventos
where
    date(fecha) >= CURDATE()
group by
    date_format(fecha,'%d/%m%Y')
```

Posteriormente desde Php bastaría recorrer el resultado, en un campo tendrías la fecha y el otro una cadena con los eventos separados por coma, puedes hacer un [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) sobre este campo y tener todos los eventos en un array para esa fecha.
He formateado la fecha, pero puedes dejarla en formato de Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

En MySql puedes utilizar una query como esta:

```
SELECT nota AS evento,
       CASE WHEN CAST(fecha AS date) = CURDATE() THEN 'Hoy' ELSE 'En los próximos días' END AS cuando
FROM eventos 
WHERE fecha >= NOW()
ORDER BY fecha ASC;
```

Filtra lo eventos cuya fecha es mayor o igual al momento de realizar la query (tiene en cuenta la hora, minutos y segundos) y para cada evento especifica si el evento es 'hoy' o 'en los próximos días'.

**Salida** (con los datos de ejemplo de la pregunta):

| evento | cuando |
| --- | --- |
| Cumple de Mica | Hoy |
| Reunion con AG | En los próximos días |